# How can I convert an associative array to a regular one

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
3113 => ['id']=> stuff
        ['dad']=> gone
```

I want to convert it to this:

```
0 => ['id']=> stuff
     ['dad']=> gone
```

Without doing something like this:

```
$surveyPages = array();

foreach($arrangedPages as $arrangedPage){
    $surveyPages[] = $arrangedPage;
}
```

Is there a built-in function to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
$surveyPages = array_values($arrangedPages);
```